# Error with timed out bluetooth connection

Tags: socketscan

I'm getting an error with the Socket 8ci after idle time on iOS.  The error is: connection to service 0x00000080 on device failed with error 305.  The only way to get it to work again is to 'forget' the bluetooth device and reconnect it.  Any insights on this problem appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Can you describe the steps to reproduce the problem a little more clearly? Approximately how long does the scanner have to be idle before you see this error? What is the battery level of the scanner? Where do you see the error - i.e. is it the response to a ScanAPI call like `Device.open(Guid)` or an OS error?

Comment: Approximately how long does the scanner have to be idle before you see this error?
Not longer than 10-15 minutes

What is the battery level of the scanner? 
70%+

Where do you see the error - i.e. is it the response to a ScanAPI call like Device.open(Guid) or an OS error? 
It is the request by the iOS device to connect to a previously paired device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is the request by the iOS device to connect to a previously paired device

When you pair an iOS device with your scanner, the iOS device starts the pairing process, but once the two devices are paired, the scanner initiates any connection to the iOS device.

**tl;dr**: You do not need to initiate the connection (in Bluetooth Settings) to your scanner once it is paired. Your scanner should automatically connect and reconnect without user intervention.

Comment: @Mark the one thing I don't understand is why you think the scanner needs to be connected manually. The scanner should remain connected until it reaches it's idle timeout and shuts off, but when you turn it back on it should immediately reconnect

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated to the new Capture SDK and am quite happy with it so far. This question probably applies to Capture as well and it's good information to use when implementing Socket support.